# If correct then goto

Tags: vbscript

I know that there is no goto function in VBS, but I am wondering if you can goto a location using a different type of function.

Here is an example of what i want:

```
Pass=inputbox("Enter Password")

:start:
if Pass = "123" then goto end else Msgbox("wrong password")
'code
goto start

:end:
Msgbox("correct")
'code
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jumping around is bad programming. Why can't you use simple loop to achieve this? Something like

```
varCheck=True
Do While varCheck
    Pass=InputBox("Enter Password")
    If Pass = "123" Then
        varCheck=False
        Exit Do
    Else
        Msgbox("Wrong Password...Try Again")
    End If
Loop
Msgbox ("After Do While")
```